# How to get rid of an instance of an object in java?

Tags: java, android, garbage-collection

I NEED to delete an instance of a class in java so I can make a new instance. The previous instance must be destroyed before I can continue. I realize that Java doesn't provide for an implicit delete, and I've been trying to force garbage collection to get rid of it using a trick with a weak reference.

This is my code:

```
private static void gc() {
    Object obj = new Object();
    WeakReference ref = new WeakReference<Object>(obj);
    obj = null;
    while(ref.get() != null) {
        System.gc();
    }
}

private void setTrack(String path){
    MediaHub current;
    if(!isPlaying){
        current = new MediaHub(title,album,titles,titlePlace,play,next,previous,volume,progress,songTitle,thisInstance,getBaseContext(),path);
    } else {
        current = null;
        gc();
        isPlaying = false;
        setTrack(path);
    }
}
```

`MediaHub` is the object I'm trying to delete an instance of and make a new one. `isPlaying` is a boolean instance variable defined as false at the top the class. Supposedly, the method `gc()` should force a garbage collection.

So far, I've had no success (for hopefully obvious reasons). So, how do I delete an instance of `MediaHub`?

EDIT: The reason I need it deleted is because there is an android MediaPlayer used in MediaHub and when I need to switch songs I end up with two songs playing over each other. I'm sort of in deep with the code and I don't want to rewrite a ton of code. So I'm really hoping for an answer here...

Comment: May I ask why you need the instance to be destroyed before you create a new one?

Comment: You are probably chasing the wrong target - you should explain the why - because the how is probably not what you think.

Comment: System.gc() **requests** a Garbage Collection. Only Android decides **when** it will be executed.

Comment: I've made an edit that answers Keppil.

Comment: Can't you just stop the current song ? there must be a functionality for switching betweens songs. Even if you could explicitly delete the media player instance I think it will still be not the way this was intended.

Comment: If the MediaHub is still playing music it is probably reachable from some active thread, possibly one it started. If so, garbage collection will not affect it. You need to stop its activity e.g. through an interrupt.

Comment: It doesn't sound like you need to 'delete' the first object, it seems like you'd just need to get control of the thread that's playing the current song. Look into the controls for your API and try that first

Comment: It happens even though I stopped the song and `release();`'d it. The problem is likely located elsewhere, and I'm not debating that. I was hoping there would be a way to get rid of an instance here.

Comment: I really encourage you to rethink this.  Your "design" is totally flawed.  "I don't want to rewrite a ton of code" is in my opinion not  a good reason to pursue a fragile, unmaintainable anti-Java approach.  Once there are no references to an object, it will be GCed at some point.  You should never rely on this happening before you create a new instance nor should you try.

Comment: I am not debating that there is more work to be done. I'm not debating I have design flaws. I just want to know if there is a trick to this so I can figure out how I want to write things. So. Is there any way.

Comment: I suggest posting a new question with a title like "How to make Android MediaPlayer switch songs?". That would be more likely to get the attention of people who can solve the real problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> So, how do I delete an instance of MediaHub?

You don't.

> The reason I need it deleted is because there is an android MediaPlayer used in MediaHub and when I need to switch songs I end up with two songs playing over each other.

Then you write a method on `MediaHub`, such as `switchSongs()`, that calls the appropriate methods on `MediaPlayer` to `stop()` the current song and `prepare()` (or `prepareAsync()`) the next song.

Comment: I've used those methods and end up with a studder in the next song. Like I commented on the question itself, I realize there is a problem elsewhere. I just want to know if there is a trick to get rid of an instance.

Comment: @user2726232: "I've used those methods and end up with a studder in the next song" -- AFAIK, most audio players use two `MediaPlayer` instances, calling `prepare()`/`prepareAsync()` on the second while the first is playing, then calling `stop()` on the first and `start()` on the second at the time of the switch. Again, this would be handled by a `switchSongs()` method. "I just want to know if there is a trick to get rid of an instance" -- not only is that not possible, it would not help your issue.

Comment: The first two sentences fixed my problem. Thank you for that, it's my first time working with mp3 files in code. Thank you for directly answering the question as well.